# Apply text wrap to CSV cell containing long string

Tags: php, csv

i am using php code to export data to CSV file.Everything is working fine as required.but problem is that when there comes long text in a cell.I want to wrap text so that i can increase cell size to handle long text.Below is my code.

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download\n");
header("Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=store_earning_report.csv");
echo "Notes \n";
echo $Notes;
echo "\n";
exit;
```

I have searched but didn't find any solution.Is there any way to handle this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are including a comma "," after each field, and "\r\n" to trigger a new line in the .csv file that is created.

A .csv is just a text file with commas used to separate the field values - So there is no way you can control the cell sizes that will appear when the file is first opened in Excel.